# Explanation of ROC function code

Tags: r, prediction, roc

I can't figure out the meaning of these three lines of code:

```
pre <- predict(fit, smot_test, type = "prob")[,2]
pre <- as.numeric(pre > i)
auc <- roc(smot_test$Class, pre)
```

What does the inequality inside the as.numeric do? What do the arguments passed to the ROC function represent?

Comment: It seems this piece of code is incomplete as `i` is not defined anywhere. This is certainly related to Area Under the Curve (`AUC`), an usual measure of goodness of fit for models of binary dependent variables.

Comment: @user3507584 yes i only kept the part of the code I didn't understand, but i has been defined earlier in the loop as :   for (i in seq(0,0.5,0.01)). What I dont get is what does the as.numeric convert from and to here, and what pre represents??

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the `pre > i` yields a `TRUE/FALSE` statement which is converted into values of `1` or `0` using the function `as.numeric`.